# Fast way to calculate difference of two balls' time in air

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

My instructor told me that if you are on an elevated height of $H$, and you throw a ball straight up with speed $V$ and another ball straight down with the same speed, the difference between the time of the balls in the air is $2V/g$. I know that this is the equation for the time of a projectile in the air if it is launched at a height of $0$. Could someone explain why this formula works for the situation mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the ball that is thrown upwards comes back to the height it was thrown from ($H$), it will have the same speed it started with (assuming negligible air resistance). So, from then on, it will fall the same way as the ball that was initially thrown down. This means that, since the downward fall time for the two balls from the starting height is the same, the difference in time will be the air time of the upward thrown ball, which is $2v/g$. The initial height $H$does not matter because the ball's path starts and ends at the same height when measuring air time.